# Change the POST method to DELETE

Tags: servlets, jersey

I built  a servlet with jersay and in the Initially of the project  all my fuctions was written with POST or GET only. I want to change the metoud to DELETE and PUT in respectively.

this is the old situation(that work well):

```
@POST
@Path("removeCompany")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response removeCompany(@QueryParam("id") long id) {

    try {
        getFacaed().removeCompany(id);
    } catch (SystemMalfunctionException | CompanyNotExistsException e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    }
    return Response.ok("Company successfully deleted").build();
}
```

I would like to change this situation:

```
    @DELETE
@Path("removeCompany")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response removeCompany(@QueryParam("id") long id) {

    try {
        getFacaed().removeCompany(id);
    } catch (SystemMalfunctionException | CompanyNotExistsException e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    }
    return Response.ok("Company successfully deleted").build();
}
```

In the old situation everything work well but when I change the method to DELETE I get this error :

[image]

Of course I keep the changes, restarts the server and restarts the project.

**editation:** 
if I change the method in postman **from** DELETE **to** POST its work although in the code It is noted that the method is DELETE.

Perhaps this will help to understand the problem.

Comment: What you're showing us looks fine. Must be something you're _not_ showing us.

Comment: I show to you all what I think that relates to the problem.
If you think that I has more part that i should to display please tell me.
I added more part to the answer maybe it's make it's more clear